# Cleaning service API using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a cleaning service API using the Django REST framework, but I think how I defined this model is not robust enough for production and in turns will make any application using this API have a very slow response, example of what I'm saying is that the model has no indexes defined whatsoever.

Running around to see if am on the right track, I came across [this link][1] and I felt this model could be better refactored. Is there anything I can do to this to make this robust? I am as new as new in Python/Django.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Cleaners(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bankName = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='zenith')
    bvn = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    verificationStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',height_field=50, width_field=50, max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,primary_key=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class CleanersWork(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cleanerId = models.ForeignKey('Cleaners', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ratings = models.IntegerField()
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    jobHistory = models.IntegerField()
    currentEarning =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class Client(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    verificationStatus = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bvn = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bankName = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',height_field=50,width_field=50,max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class Offering(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    totalJobPosted = models.IntegerField()
    ratings = models.IntegerField()
    availableFunds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class Bookings(models.Model):
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client', null=False, blank=False, default='Client_Id') # Who is booking who ? I also don't want to CASCADE upon delete, we will need record of booking either is client deleted or not.
    cleaner_id = models.ForeignKey('Cleaners', null=False, blank=False, default='Cleaner_Id') # Who is being booked ? I also don't want to CASCADE upon delete, we will need record of booking either is cleaner deleted or not.
    startDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    startTime = models.TimeField()
    extras = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Here is my serializers.py in case you need a reference to it:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from laundry.models import Cleaners,CleanersWork,Client,Offering,Bookings

class CleanerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cleaners
        fields = ('created','firstName','lastName','location','address','bankName','bvn','verificationStatus','phone')

class CleanersWorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CleanersWork
        fields = ('created','cleanerId','ratings','availability','jobHistory','currentEarning')

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('created','firstName','lastName','address','verificationStatus','bvn','bankName','phone')

class OfferingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        fields = ('created','client_id','totalJobPosted','ratings','availableFunds')

class BookingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookings
        fields =  ('client_id', 'cleaner_id', 'startDate','startTime', 'extras', 'price', 'notes', 'created')
```

Answer (score 3):

Are the cleaners and clients supposed to be authenticated, maybe they should inherit from AUTH_USER_MODE or a base user? When using the ORM you want the object to have the name to the models on the foreign Key i.e `client = models.ForeignKey(Client)`. By default, all these models have indexes for the pk, are your querying every object using the pk (i.e the id)?